# Modeling question, tiki torch.

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I had an idea strike me the other night of modeling an exterior scene, which I know how to model except for the tiki torches. I tried the cast modifier and it does not work well, at least not with a grid object set to x=8, y=8. I can work out everything that would run the z axis, but the mesh that would weave between the "fingers" of the z axis going across the x axis (while in front ortho), I'm not sure how to achieve the correct affect. I've included a reference photo from the yard to help clarify if there is any misunderstanding. I want to "weave" my mesh along the x axis between the adjoining objects if it's possible.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could all be done with curves.

Starting with a circle curve

[image]

Then add another curve for the vertical elements, give it some extrusion.

[image]

Make an array and use a curve modefier to guide the array around the circle curve.

[image]

Create another circle, subdivide it and weave it around the verical elements.

[image]

Duplicate that curve and rotate it to create the torch.

[image]